# Testing the joint hypothesis of a variable that is linear and quadratic

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing

I have a regression equation of the form

`y=b0+b1*x1+b2*x2+b3*x2^2+b4*x3`

I am told to test the joint hypothesis that x1 and x2 do not affect the response. Since x2 appears as a linear and quadratic term, should I test

`H0: b1=b2=b3=0` or

`H0: b1=b2=0`

My intuition is leaning towards `H0: b1=b2=b3=0`

Comment: An argument could be made for multiple conflicting answers: it depends on how you interpret the phrase "$x_2$ affects the response."  Why not return to the person who requested this test and ask them to clarify which hypothesis they intend you to test?

Comment: whuber is right that your client (professor...) should clarify. However, I interpret this to mean that, if $x_2$ does not affect the response, then we should stop measuring it, meaning that we won't be able to feed it into a regression equation with $x_2^2$.

Comment: @Dave Thank you for the feedback. I have asked for clarification.